issue with time zones in dataframe and POSIXct data
I have a bunch of timedates with different time zones - I am able to generate a dataframe with these as different columns. It looks something like this:
timedate <- c("2024-03-31T03:14:00", "2024-03-24T01:07:00", "2024-04-09T22:45:00")
zones <- c("UTC", "Australia/Brisbane", "Australia/Canberra")
df <- tibble(timedate, zones)
df

> A tibble: 3 × 2
> timedate            zones             
>   <chr>               <chr>             
> 1 2024-03-31T03:14:00 UTC               
> 2 2024-03-24T01:07:00 Australia/Brisbane
> 3 2024-04-09T22:45:00 Australia/Canberra

I know that the following works to create a col of POSIX class data...
df <- mutate(df
        ,timedatezone = as.POSIXct(timedate,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = 'UTC'))
df

> A tibble: 3 × 3
> timedate            zones              timedatezone       
>   <chr>               <chr>              <dttm>             
> 1 2024-03-31T03:14:00 UTC                2024-03-31 03:14:00
> 2 2024-03-24T01:07:00 Australia/Brisbane 2024-03-24 01:07:00
> 3 2024-04-09T22:45:00 Australia/Canberra 2024-04-09 22:45:00

but... the following does not
df <- mutate(df
        ,timedatezone = as.POSIXct(timedate,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = zones))

> Error in `mutate()`:
> In argument: `timedatezone = as.POSIXct(timedate, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = zones)`.
> Caused by error in `strptime()`:
> invalid 'tz' value
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I feel like I am missing something incredibly basic, but I have googled and googled and I cannot figure out a fix.
Ultimately, I would like a column with values which know which timezone they are in or a column will all values in a single time zone (where I know what that timezone is).

You can't have multiple timezones for a single POSIXct vector. The best you could do is a list, like: Map(as.POSIXct, df$timedate, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz=df$zones)

ohh, i did not realise that. I thought each element of the vector could have its own timezone

ultimately I want a column with a consistent time zone.

I suggest you use the datetimeoffset package.
df <- data.frame(timedate = c("2024-03-31T03:14:00", "2024-03-24T01:07:00", "2024-04-09T22:45:00"), 
                 zones = c("UTC", "Australia/Brisbane", "Australia/Canberra"))

library(datetimeoffset)
df$parsed <- as_datetimeoffset(df$timedate, tz = df$zones) |> as.POSIXct(tz = "UTC")
df
#             timedate              zones              parsed
#1 2024-03-31T03:14:00                UTC 2024-03-31 03:14:00
#2 2024-03-24T01:07:00 Australia/Brisbane 2024-03-23 15:07:00
#3 2024-04-09T22:45:00 Australia/Canberra 2024-04-09 12:45:00


Well this worked. thanks.

Perhaps this'll help, if you want one consolidated datetime column (in UTC):
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(timedatezone = as.POSIXct(timedate, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = zones)) |>
  ungroup()

Result
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  timedate            zones              timedatezone       
  <chr>               <chr>              <dttm>             
1 2024-03-31T03:14:00 UTC                2024-03-31 03:14:00
2 2024-03-24T01:07:00 Australia/Brisbane 2024-03-23 15:07:00
3 2024-04-09T22:45:00 Australia/Canberra 2024-04-09 12:45:00


this sounds like the best option. I have some 'NA' rows and this seems to be causing difficulty. This should work once i figure out a fix for the NA rows

Be careful that this seems to take the timezone for the output from the first row of the data.frame/tibble, and will vary silently without warning that there has been this coercion taking place.

i filtered out all the NA rows, but it seems I'm not sure what the following means

df$timedatezone
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: timedatezone.


To unify all times to one timezone, use as.POSIXct() in mapply(), providing times, zones, and formats as vectors, element-wise. Initially converted to "POSIXct", it returns numeric (seconds since 1970-01-01). Apply as.POSIXct() again, setting the target timezone, such as "UTC".
> f <- \(x, tz, format="%FT%T", new.tz="UTC") {
+   xtz <-  mapply(as.POSIXct, x, format=format, tz=tz)
+   as.POSIXct(xtz, tz=new.tz)
+ }
> with(df, f(x=timedate, tz=zones))  ## 'UTC', default
      2024-03-31T03:14:00       2024-03-24T01:07:00       2024-04-09T22:45:00 
"2024-03-31 03:14:00 UTC" "2024-03-23 15:07:00 UTC" "2024-04-09 12:45:00 UTC" 
> with(df, f(x=timedate, tz=zones, new.tz='America/Los_Angeles'))
      2024-03-31T03:14:00       2024-03-24T01:07:00       2024-04-09T22:45:00 
"2024-03-30 20:14:00 PDT" "2024-03-23 08:07:00 PDT" "2024-04-09 05:45:00 PDT" 
> df |> transform(tdz=f(x=timedate, zones, 'America/Los_Angeles'))
                               timedate              zones                 tdz
2024-03-31T03:14:00 2024-03-31T03:14:00                UTC 2024-03-30 20:14:00
2024-03-24T01:07:00 2024-03-24T01:07:00 Australia/Brisbane 2024-03-23 08:07:00
2024-04-09T22:45:00 2024-04-09T22:45:00 Australia/Canberra 2024-04-09 05:45:00

Note: The "POSIXct" class is actually a numeric vector with a "tzone" attribute to specify the timezone.

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(timedate = c("2024-03-31T03:14:00", "2024-03-24T01:07:00", 
"2024-04-09T22:45:00"), zones = c("UTC", "Australia/Brisbane", 
"Australia/Canberra")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


could you break it down a bit more for my benefit.  I am not familiar with this way of making a function? In fact I am not able to follow what you have done.  thanks in advance for your help

@fakefake Can you be more specific, please?

I do not understand the first line beginning with "f <-". It looked to me like you were making a function, but it was beyond the level of the functions that I have made in the past

@fakefake \(x) is just an alias for function(x), you can also use the latter in current R version.

I think this could be simplified a bit - I seem to get the same results without using the attr<- part: f <- function(x, tz, format="%FT%T", new.tz="UTC") {xtz <- mapply(as.POSIXct, x, format=format, tz=tz); as.POSIXct(xtz, tz=new.tz)}

@thelatemail You're right, the attribute on the numerics was redundant. The actual job is done by the second as.POSIXct(<NUM>, tz=new.tz).
